# entity has no primary key attribute defined : JPA

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

i am using Eclipse neon.i am new to JPA. i always getting this error. 
please help to fix this.

below is my POJO class

```
package myJPA;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * The persistent class for the user_online database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="user_online")
@NamedQuery(name="UserOnline.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM UserOnline u")

public class UserOnline implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="mem_id")
     @Id
    private int memId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date time;

    public UserOnline() {
    }

    public int getMemId() {
        return this.memId;
    }

    public void setMemId(int memId) {
        this.memId = memId;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

my persistence.xml contents are below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myJPA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>myJPA.UserOnline</class>
        <properties>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

when i run my main class with this error i get these errors

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Eclipselink_JPA
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at myJPA.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Main.java

```
package myJPA;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "Eclipselink_JPA" );

      EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );
      UserOnline u = new UserOnline();
      u.setMemId(999);
      u.setTime(new Date(0));
      entitymanager.persist( u );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

      entitymanager.close( );
      emfactory.close( );



}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityManagerFactory initialization should be changed to below :

```
EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "myJPA" );
```

You have to provide name of your defined persistence unit to create factory from it.